# How to convert lightsail server(basic account) domain into https?

Tags: apache, flask, https, amazon-lightsail

1. I bought a godaddy domain and managed to map it to the lightsail ip address.
2. I used "let's encrypt" certbot to issued a license to that domain name. Successful.("Congratulations! You have successfully enabled https://jacky2020.com")
3. http works, https still doesn't.

Tutorials on Amazon website does not seem to work on the basic account($5/month)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you opened up port 443 / https in the Lightsail firewall for that instance?